# can not convert it into content-type:application/json

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

```
let formData2 = new FormData();
                    formData2.append('_token', vm.response._token);
                    formData2.append('file', vm.response.content[i].path);
                    formData2.append('type', vm.response.content[i].type);

                        // this part is progress bar

                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.open("POST", "page/file/create/upload", true);
                            if (xhr.upload) {
                                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                        progressBar.max = e.total;
                                        progressBar.value = e.loaded;
                                        display.innerText = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%';
                                    }
                                }
                                xhr.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
                                    progressBar.value = 0;
                                    display.innerText = '0%';
                                }
                                xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
                                    progressBar.value = e.loaded;
                                }
                            }
                            xhr.send(formData2);
```

i saw in network tab after pressing f12 that in response-header my content-type is text/html. i think this is the main reason of getting 500 error. because in ajax needs JSON. i am working with laravel and my controller get NULL.
 so how can i covert it into json?

Comment: try adding `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');` after xhr.open(.......)

Comment: thankz sir. yes it is working now. content-type has changed but get another error(419). but i have send token. when i clicked on the upolad tab in network . it shows method not allowed.

Comment: Try doing this instead `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', vm.response._token);` or may be in your case `xhr.setRequestHeader('_token', vm.response._token);`. Remove this line or comment it out `formData2.append('_token', vm.response._token);`

Comment: sir, see the answr part i am givvving. basically i want to show u  the code.

Comment: and why i am getting method not allow. i am uploading a file, so i have to do a POST call, then why laravel gives me method not allowed

Comment: Route::post('page/file/create/upload','PageController@addNewPageFile');   //File submission

Comment: Please give this one a try `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))`;

Comment: Good morning. Yeah definitely i will. I will let u know

Answer (score 0):

```
let formData2 = new FormData();
                    formData2.append('file', vm.response.content[i].path);
                    // this part is progress bar

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", "page/file/create/upload", true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', vm.response._token);

                    if (xhr.upload) {
                        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                progressBar.max = e.total;
                                progressBar.value = e.loaded;
                                display.innerText = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%';
                            }
                        }
                        xhr.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
                            progressBar.value = 0;
                            display.innerText = '0%';
                        }
                        xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
                            progressBar.value = e.loaded;
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send(formData2);
```

@ksoni  still m getting 500 error code. and content-header is still text/html. what mistake i have done with my formData2(image or any file). what is the procedure. can u explain a bit.